# Create rule with VBA that adds a category to an email when received

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like to create a rule with VBA, not run a script in a rule, that will add a category (Red) to emails coming from a particular domain when received. I could figure the receiving and particular domain part, but am struggling with the correct VBA syntax for categories. The colour of the category is Red, and the name of the category is "SPAM". Here is my latest attempt:

```
Dim oRuleNew As Outlook.Rule
Dim oCategoryRuleConditionSpam As Outlook.CategoryRuleCondition

Set oCategoryRuleConditionSpam = oRuleNew.Conditions.Category
With oCategoryRuleConditionSpam
    .Enabled = True
    .Categories = "SPAM"
End With
```

Basically I cannot find out how to assign the right value to .Categories.. any help would be really appreciated.

Also tried:
    .Categories.Add ("SPAM")

Actually, perhaps that the below is better suited to the task:

```
Dim oRuleNew As Outlook.Rule
Dim oCategoryRuleActionSpam As Outlook.RuleAction

Set oCategoryRuleActionSpam = oRuleNew.Action.AssignToCategory
With oCategoryRuleActionSpam
    .Enabled = True
    .Categories = "SPAM"
End With
```

But now I receive error 13 :(

Found it!

```
Dim oRuleNew As Outlook.Rule
Dim oCategoryRuleActionSpam As Outlook.RuleAction
Dim aCat(0) As String

aCat(0) = "SPAM"
Set oCategoryRuleActionSpam = oRuleNew.Action.AssignToCategory
With oCategoryRuleActionSpam
    .Enabled = True
    .Categories = aCat
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need set the category name to the [Categories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860423(v=office.15).aspx) property of the MailItem class. Categories is a delimited string of category names that have been assigned to an Outlook item. This property uses the character specified in the value name, sList, under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International in the Windows registry, as the delimiter for multiple categories.

```
mailItem.Categories = "SPAM"
```

Comment: Hi Eugene, thanks again for your help. Unfortunately it returns Error 438 :(

Comment: It looks like the message is already marked with the category. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

```
Dim oRuleNew As Outlook.Rule
Dim oCategoryRuleActionSpam As Outlook.RuleAction
Dim aCat(0) As String

aCat(0) = "SPAM"
Set oCategoryRuleActionSpam = oRuleNew.Action.AssignToCategory
With oCategoryRuleActionSpam
    .Enabled = True
    .Categories = aCat
End With
```

Comment: Do you need to create a rule?